# Get DISPLAY environment variable from a local terminal to the Visual Studio Code terminal through SSH

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, x11

I'm using VScode with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and working through an SSH connection.

Unfortunately, the Remote - SSH extension by Microsoft doesn't enable X11 forwarding ([#267](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/267)), and thus an extension such as [Remote X11](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spadin.remote-x11) has been created.

Sadly, this extension doesn't work for me as I'm working through a jump host/gateway, and therefore have to manually change the DISPLAY variable in the VScode terminal to the DISPLAY variable found in another terminal that is used for displaying stuff.

I guess it is possible to get the DISPLAY variable by running `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/<pid>/environ | grep DISPLAY`([Environment variables of a running process on Unix?](https://serverfault.com/a/66366)), with the `<pid>` being run from the local terminal, and now it's just a problem of automating the search for this process.

So i guess the stuff I'm asking for, is a way to:

1. Get the pid from a process on a local terminal
2. Get the DISPLAY variable from this process
3. Set the DISPLAY variable in every newly opened terminal in VScode (perhaps running step 2 in the workspace-settings.json)

PS. I'm using the VcXsrv X Server